# Laravel dynamic validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm using Laravel and I have a custom validation. I want to pass some value to the validation class and validate it against the DB so I keep all the validation logic in the validation class. Here's my code but the validation error is not triggered:

```
public function rules() {

    $userCode = UserCode::getCode();

    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|email',

        $userCode => 'unique:user_codes,code,'. $userCode
    ];

    return $rules;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? the validation is never triggered even if the value `$userCode` already exists in the DB. The validation is triggered if the request contains bad email for example.

Edit: I have this user_codes table that has a code column that must be kept unique. `UserCode::getCode()` produces this code. So I also want to check if this code is unique or not in the table user_codes before passing it to the controller. I already have the custom validator but the problem is that I want it to also validate this code. The validator works fine with the other request body. The problem is that this code is not passed from the request body but it is simply generated from another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using a `FormRequest` class with the [prepareForValidation()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#preparing-input-for-validation) method. It should look something like this:

```php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class WhateverRequest extends FormRequest
{
    protected function prepareForValidation(): void
    {
        $this->merge([
            'user_code' => UserCode::getCode(),
        ]);
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'user_code' => 'unique:user_codes,code'
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that prepareForValidation is called before rules or that it was called at all.

Comment: It is actually a built-in method in the framework. You can read about it in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/validation#preparing-input-for-validation. If you are curious about how it is implemented you can check this trait: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidatesWhenResolvedTrait.php

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear, I understand you have a column named by `code`

and you want to be unique, you can add usercode to request,

```
request()->merge(['userCode'=>$userCode]);
```

then

```
$rules = [
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|email',

        'userCode' => 'unique:user_codes,code,'.UserCode::getId().',id'
    ];
```

I answered what I understand from your question

Comment: Please check my edit

Comment: $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|email',

        'userCode' => 'unique:user_codes,code'
    ];

Comment: userCode doesn't come from the request. It is a value generated by a method call.

Answer (score 0):

Okay start with the following:

```
php artisan make:rule SomeAwesomeRule
```

```php
Then edit that created Rule
class SomeAwesomeRule implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
       //some logic that needs to be handled...
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return __('Some.nice.translated.message');
    }
}
```

And then apply the rule

```php
$rules = [
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|email',

        'userCode' => new SomeAwesomeRule(#this is a constructor so pass away)

    ];
```

Comment: Please check my edit

Comment: then my solution is bonkers... but if your usercode is unique why not make sure in the model that it is checked. I don't know how your user code is build but if you check if the usercode is unique within the function getCode then you should be golden.

Comment: Because I want to separate the validation logic from the controller. So that all the validation happen before the controller.

Comment: Observers, Middleware etc????? Look at the awnser of Rabie, do{} while{} 

also I have made an example observer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71234431/solved-how-to-update-parent-model-in-laravel/71237947?noredirect=1#comment125941072_71237947

maybe this helps?

Comment: I don't think it is worth it to create an observer just for this unique case.

Answer (score 0):

see

```
$rules = [
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|email',
    
            'userCode' => 'unique:user_codes,code'
        ];
```

//or

```
$userCode="";

do{
$userCode = UserCode::getCode();
}
while(UserCode::where('code',$userCode)->first());
// after loop you sure the code is unique
  $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|email',
 
        ];
```

Comment: This works but how can I show the exception that is thrown when the unique validation fails? I would like to show the normal message not a custom one.

Comment: I think you should not show any exception because you generate code, it's not given from the user (client)